# converting links data from list to series changes the links inside the final series (I don't want it clickable just the data frame to be perfect)

Tags: python, pandas, https

I have a list which is just
`list_1=[ab1234,ac1234,ad3214,bc1245]`

What I did was run `static=https:\\sab.com\a\`

```
list_new=[]

for every in list_1:

    new=static+every

    list_new.append(new)
```

Till here the links are as they were supposed to be  but as soon as I do

`links=pd.Series(list_new)`

The result is a series of clickable links with each link as

`https:\\sab.com\a...`

At first glance I thought it is just now displayed but as soon as I click it , it is literallt ... in the end

I did tried this approach of not using `https:\\` and just create links using same method and it creates the below one in pandas series

`'sab.com\a\ab1234'` and so on for all values

as soon as I do `df[links].apply(lambda x: 'https:\\' + str(x))`

the same thing happens again with just `https:\\sab.com\a...`
seems to be a problem with https:\ can someone help in undestanding what is going wrong and what can I do to correct the links

Note: all links are hypothetical as this is a company data and I cannot show the actual links--sorry for that

Comment: I think problem is for clickable links need more complicated solution like `links=pd.Series(list_new)`

Comment: nothing from there works as I have a list made of links and when I call it into dataframe those links get disturbed I dont want it clickable I just want to data to be shown perfectly in dataframe